# transpose using php after querying a database

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am using PHP to query a MYSQL database, and I am trying to output the data to an excel file.

I have used phpexcel, csv, etc. With each i have successfully been able to output the data to an excel file, but I can't seem to transpose it in the excel (transpose- flip all columns into rows, and rows into columns)

I can't find any tutorials to help me out.

My question is, is there a way to use php to transpose those rows and columns from MYSQL and import them into an excel file?

thanks!

**CODE:**

```
exportMysqlToCsv($tablename,$tokenmain, $id);
function exportMysqlToCsv($tablename,$tokenmain, $id, $filename = 'Results.csv'){
    $sql_query = "select * from $tablename where token=1";

  // Gets the data from the database
   $result = mysql_query($sql_query);

    $f = fopen('php://temp', 'wt');
    $first = true;

//trying to transpose the data 
function transpose($array) {
    array_unshift($array, null);
    return call_user_func_array('array_map', $array);}

//inserting it into the excel file  
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        if ($first) {

            fputcsv($f, array_keys($row));

            $first = false;

         }

      fputcsv($f, $row);
    }
} //end while
```

**Database sample:**

```
=======================================
|  Male/female  |    Favorite artist  |
=====+========+===============+=======|
|    F          | Britney Spears      |
|-------------------------------------|
```

**What I want it to look like:**

```
=====================================
|Question          |  Answer        |
=====+========+===============+=====|
|   Male/female    |   F            |
|----+--------+---------------+-----|
| Favorite artist  | Britney Spears |
|----+--------+---------------+-----|
```

**HUGE NOTE:** There is no changing the database/hardcoding out the array in php. I want it all dynamic and the database is going to stay the way it is

Comment: You should post your existing code, so we can see how you're creating your Excel files.

Comment: posted it. The transpose code has been placed throughout this file as well.

Comment: you should post some sample data and then the final result that you want, you might be able to do this with a query and not in php.

Comment: What's the structure of your array?  If you can get your array structured correctly, writing it to file will be a piece of cake.

Comment: I have updated the question. Any thoughts?

Comment: Has your db table only 2 columns and the Excel table only 2 rows?

Comment: no that is just a small sample. The database is huge, which is why I don't want to change the database

Comment: Will you have an identifying column for each row in the database? If not, the solution is simple, but I don't see how you could tie each row in the resulting transposed table with the original database without it. If so, could you add that to your example?

Comment: I don't need an identifying column for each row..So I wouldn't need the headers- "Question" and "Answer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question this is my code using PHPExcel:

```
$col=1; // 1-based index
while($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$row= 1;

    foreach ($row_data as $key=>$value) {

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
$row++;
    }
    $col++;

}

$row=1;
while($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
$col=0;

    foreach($row_data as $value) {

   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
        $row++;

    $col++;}
}
```

Switch up the columns (col) and rows (row), so that the columns in the database become the rows in the excel file and the same for the rows to columns.